# How to remove empty query string from url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a web-site and some pages have a question mark on the end of url. That looks like:
`zip-da.ru/catalog/bumps.html?`

and I want rewrite it to: 
`zip-da.ru/catalog/bumps.html`

How can I do it using .htaccess?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\s
RewriteRule ^  %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=302]
```

`?` in the end will strip query string from your URLs.

Comment: It doesn't works :(. It redirects http://zip-da.ru/catalogue? to zip-da.ru/index.php

Comment: It definitely works. `/catalog/bumps.html?` gets redirected to `/catalog/bumps.html` by stripping `?`

Comment: @GregoryZhdanov share your htaccess it can be have some another rule

Comment: I paste my .htaccess to Pastebin http://pastebin.com/Lu8cnWiK. I hope it'll help you. There is 301 redirects in the end of that file.

Comment: This rule must be placed as very first rule just below `RewriteBase /` line and then test it after clearing your browser cache.